# Need help in setting up a transient using API Key and if possible updating it in the ACF field

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, api, transient

I am trying to set up a shortcode that will fetch Moz API data but I am facing issues. Sometimes, it returns values to 0, and sometimes it works. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Might be I need to delete the existing transients or to check if value = 0 in transients. Further, I am using the same code for retrieving different MOZ API data by rewriting this function using different transient keys. Can I merge this code into one? Like [moz_score_da] and [moz_score_pa] Here is the code: The major issue is that I am stuck with some transient values returning zero and then I have to delete them manually and it pulls back the correct value.

I am using this shortcode in the ACF field. If possible, kindly guide me If I can directly update the acf field using transients and shortcodes.

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
    return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');


function moz_score_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'domain' => get_the_title(),
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( ! $domain )
        return; // No domain, nothing to return

    $cache_key = 'agency_moz_score_' . $domain;
    if ( false === $seo_grade = get_transient( $cache_key ) ) {
        // Setting Moz API connection
        $accessID = "mozscape-####"; // * Add unique Access ID
        $secretKey = "####"; // * Add unique Secret Key
        $expires = time() + 300;
        $SignInStr = $accessID. "\n" .$expires;
        $binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $SignInStr, $secretKey, true);
        $SafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
        // Connecting to Moz API url
        $reqUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/".urlencode($domain)."?Cols=103079215108&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$SafeSignature;
        // Send request with curl
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        $curlhandle = curl_init($reqUrl);
        curl_setopt_array($curlhandle, $opts);
        $content = curl_exec($curlhandle);
        curl_close($curlhandle);

        // Getting 'pda' from Moz API and then rounding
        $resObj = json_decode($content);
        $seo_grade = $resObj->pda;
        $seo_grade = round($seo_grade, 0);

        set_transient( $cache_key, $seo_grade, (60*60*72) );
    }

    return $seo_grade;
}

add_shortcode( 'moz_score','moz_score_shortcode' );
```

The second code is

```
function moz_pa_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'domain' => get_the_title(),
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( ! $domain )
        return; // No domain, nothing to return

    $cache_key_pa = 'agency_moz_pa_' . $domain;

    if ( false === $seop_grade = get_transient( $cache_key_pa ) ) {
        // Setting Moz API connection
        $accessID = "mozscape-#####"; // * Add unique Access ID
        $secretKey = "######"; // * Add unique Secret Key
        $expires = time() + 300;
        $SignInStr = $accessID. "\n" .$expires;
        $binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $SignInStr, $secretKey, true);
        $SafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
        // Connecting to Moz API url
        $reqUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/".urlencode($domain)."?Cols=103079215140&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$SafeSignature;
        // Send request with curl
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        $curlhandle = curl_init($reqUrl);
        curl_setopt_array($curlhandle, $opts);
        $content = curl_exec($curlhandle);
        curl_close($curlhandle);

        // Getting 'pda' from Moz API and then rounding
        $resObj = json_decode($content);
        $seop_grade = $resObj->upa;
        $seop_grade = round($seop_grade, 0);

        set_transient( $cache_key_pa, $seop_grade, (60*60*72) );
    }

    return $seop_grade;
}

add_shortcode( 'moz_pa','moz_pa_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Are you sure the 0s aren't coming from your API? `round(null, 0)` will give you 0.

Comment: If you want to merge this code (and I'm not sure the requests are completely the same? Your Cols parameters are different, but I don't know the API to know if that's significant) then you could e.g. save the result of the API call as a transient and have both functions read that and parse out the value, or you could e.g. have both requests write both transients (commonising the request code).

Comment: I'm also not sure why you want to show an SEO evaluation on the pages themselves? Is that what you're trying to do? Why would you want to show that to the web site user?

Comment: Actually, it's not for showing on each page but a CPT with title value as a URL will be shown.

Comment: @Rup, Yes because if a delete a transient, it will be updated with the correct value. For example if 10 website stats are fetched only 2-3 are 0 and when I refetch them they are correct.

Comment: @Rup, I can adjust the Col's parameters. That's not an issue. Requests are same too. They just need a different   $seop_grade = $resObj->upa;  ,  $seop_grade = $resObj->pda; here.

Comment: OK, but I'd still guess you're getting the 0s from the first requests even in the repeat requests give you the numbers you want. I'd try tracing out $domain, $content, $resObj and $seop_grade for all of the requests e.g. with error_log and print_r(..., true).

Comment: @Rup. might be the issue is with firing multiple API requests for different stats. When we can get them from one?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was the problem. If you're worried about the API end of things then I'd capture or trace out the responses so you can see them, or if you're worried about the curl specifics you could use wp_remote_get instead. But you can combine pda and upa into a single request yes.

Comment: Kindly guide me how to combine it. Also is it possible, if I check that value = 0 and it will refetch the stats?

Comment: @Rup read it on stackexchange "Maybe, but in my case set_transient() has failed when re-used without delete_transient() first. For some time I thought the problem was that the array I was saving as a transient was too large but that wasn't it. I recommend that you delete the transient first if you're having a problem." Can you help me with it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that: I can't see a way that set_transient would fail unless the old transient had a value === false, but I'm not sure it's possible to save a false boolean in the database. If you did want to, just `delete_transient( $cache_key );` before you set_transient - or check the return value of set_transient, and if it failed then delete_transient and set_transient again.

Comment: Can you help me to merge this code into one. Might be that works

Comment: @Rup I have some further issues. The transients will never auto-populate after expiration and we need to manually refresh the page where we put the shortcode to display the DA and PA. Further, on page refresh, all transients don't be updated once and require many refreshes to fill the data. Is it possible with Cron job to update them again on expiry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here's an attempt to fetch both pda and upa in a single request:

```
/**
 * Make a Moz v1 URL Metrics request for a given domain
 *
 * @see https://moz.com/help/links-api/v1-archive/v1-url-metrics
 * @see https://moz.com/help/links-api/v1-archive/response-fields
 * @param $domain
 */
function moz_v1_links_api_request($domain) {
    if ( !$domain ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    $cache_key = 'agency_moz_url_metrics_' . $domain;
    $url_metrics = get_transient( $cache_key );

    if ( false === $url_metrics ) {
        // Setting Moz API connection
        $accessID = "mozscape-####"; // * Add unique Access ID
        $secretKey = "####"; // * Add unique Secret Key
        $expires = time() + 300;
        $SignInStr = $accessID. "\n" .$expires;
        $binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $SignInStr, $secretKey, true);
        $SafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
        // Connecting to Moz API url
        // 103079215140 = 0x1800000024, the flags for pda, upa, ueid and uu respectively
        $reqUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/".urlencode($domain)."?Cols=103079215140&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$SafeSignature;

        // Send request with curl
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        $curlhandle = curl_init($reqUrl);
        curl_setopt_array($curlhandle, $opts);
        $content = curl_exec($curlhandle);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($curlhandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curlhandle);

        if ( $status_code < 200 || $status_code >= 300 ) {
            // HTTP request failed
            error_log('moz_v1_links_api_request for ' . $domain . ' failed: ' . $status_code . ' ' . print_r( $content, true) );

            // Cache an empty object for 30 seconds so we retry shortly
            $url_metrics = new stdClass();
            set_transient( $cache_key, $url_metrics, 30 );
        } else {
            // Cache the object returned for three days
            $url_metrics = json_decode($content);
            set_transient( $cache_key, $url_metrics, (60*60*72) );
        }
    }

    return $url_metrics;
}

function moz_score_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'domain' => get_the_title(),
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( ! $domain )
        return NULL; // No domain, nothing to return

    $url_metrics = moz_v1_links_api_request( $domain );

    // Getting 'pda' from Moz API and then rounding
    if ( isset( $url_metrics->pda ) ) {
        $seo_grade = $url_metrics->pda;
        if (is_numeric($seo_grade)) {
            $seo_grade = round($seo_grade, 0);
        }
    } else {
        // No value returned
        $seo_grade = NULL;
    }

    return $seo_grade;
}

add_shortcode( 'moz_score','moz_score_shortcode' );

function moz_pa_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'domain' => get_the_title(),
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( ! $domain )
        return NULL; // No domain, nothing to return

    $url_metrics = moz_v1_links_api_request( $domain );

    // Getting 'upa' from Moz API and then rounding
    if ( isset( $url_metrics->upa ) ) {
        $seop_grade = $url_metrics->upa;
        if ( is_numeric( $seop_grade ) ) {
            $seop_grade = round($seop_grade, 0);
        }
    } else {
        // No value returned
        $seop_grade = NULL;
    }

    return $seop_grade;
}

add_shortcode( 'moz_pa','moz_pa_shortcode' );
```

or a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/RupW/541e316b241f22e40ce74d0c42dfc445). Note that:

- I've copied your curl code since I assume it's working fine, but there's also wp_request_get you could use instead
- I'm now testing the HTTP status code returned by curl and logging an error
- I'm also checking that the upa or pda value you've extracted is numeric before trying to round it, which I think is where you're going wrong: I'd guess you're getting null values here rounded to 0 because you're not noticing you're getting errors from the API
- the API you're calling is out of date and there's a new API you should be using instead
- this version of the API also supports [batched requests](https://moz.com/help/links-api/v1-archive/best-practices) which you could use instead for all of your domains at once, rather than fetching them one at a time like this.

Comment: Super, Rup, It worked like a charm. The answer is very detailed and solved the issue.